# Securing backend code for client's side deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have EKS cluster where my application code resides in pods (container).
Client want this cluster to be hosted on their AWS cloud. How do I make sure that my code will be secure in client's environment. How do I make sure that he cannot copy or has no access to the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At most you can compile and obfuscate it with whatever tools your language provides. This is generally pointless though, decompilers are very very good these days.

Comment: But there should be a way around it. there are many product based companies out there, how do they make sure that there code is safe (out of client's reach) while deploying the service in client's cloud.

Comment: Contracts, end user license agreements, and other legal solutions. This is not a problem you can solve with technology.